# Marker shows old location and new location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javafx

In a javaFX application I'm setting the marker.setPosition(latlng) to change marker location. But in the map it still shows the marker in old location. If there are five events and there shows five markers.
But when I resize map other four markers gets disappeared and only the new location is visible. Which is the desired output.

```
  var map;
    var latlng;
    var markerMap = {};
    function loadmap() {

        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.768378333333334, 79.91390166666666);
        var options = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), options);
    }
    function addMarker(mapId, x, y) {
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
        if (markerMap[mapId] == null) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                //icon: carMarkerImage,
                title: "Vehicle",
                autoPan: true
            });

            var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                // You can pass some content to the function like addMarker(x, y, content)
                content: "some content for your marker "+mapId
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infobulle.open(map, marker);
            });

            markerMap[mapId] = marker;
        } else {
            var marker = markerMap[mapId];
            marker.setPosition(latlng);

        }
        goo
```

JAVAFX ---------

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    String csvFileName = csvButtonMap.get(event.getSource());
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();

    if (!"Pause".equals(button.getText()) && !"Continue".equals(button.getText())) {
        button.setText("Pause");

        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(csvFileName);
        Thread vThread = new Thread(vehicle);

        vehicle.speedPropertyProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newVlaue) -> {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(vehicle.getLatitudeProperty());
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(vehicle.getLongitudeProperty());
                    String setMarker = "addMarker(" + vThread.getId() + "," + latitude + "," + longitude + ")".trim();

                    webEngine.executeScript(setMarker);

                }
            });

        });


        vThread.setDaemon(true);
        button.setId(String.valueOf(vThread.getId()));
        lockObjMap.put(vThread.getId(), new Object());
        button.getParent().setId(String.valueOf(vThread.getId()));
        statusLabel.setText("Vehicle " + csvFileName + " stared!");

        vThread.start();
```

This is what happens.
[image]
Any idea?

Comment: I would like to see how/where you call addMarker(), and how/where you add a new markerMap instance

Comment: This platform run later will be called in every second. So lat and long gets updated in every second. I want to show only the latest updated location of the marker.